# Phonon does not render video

Tags: c++, qt, video, phonon

When I was trying to run the `Qt::Phonon::VideoPlayer` demo code, I got strange bug. The video is not rendered while sound is played well. What's wrong?

Here's my code:

```
if (ui->widget)
{
    Phonon::VideoPlayer *player = new Phonon::VideoPlayer(ui->widget);

    player->load(MediaSource("D:/Films/19.wmv"));

    connect(player, SIGNAL(finished()), player, SLOT(deleteLater()));

    player->play();
}
```

`ui->widget` is a `QWidget` element on my window. The code is run on button click (button is also in the window).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you are missing a codec on your OS. Have you tried this with many different video files, do they all behave the same way?

Comment: Yes. They do. I do not see any video on my Windows7 PC but i do on my Linux PC =)

Answer (score 3):

Found this bug surely unexpected: frame size was `1x1 px`. Did not know what to do and the most surprising was the solution i took a glance somewhere over the internet:

```
player->setMinimumSize(ui->playerWidget->width(), ui->playerWidget->height());
```